# What are the optimal ways to learn undergraduate level math?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, learning

I have recently dipped my toes into the topic of Machine Learning / Deep Learning and I would like to understand the underlying mathematical concepts.

I'm looking for an optimal way to learn the basics (mostly what can be found in a typical undergraduate math curriculum).

Going back to university would be the simplest choice but I don't have the time to do so. Another problem with it is that from my experience it is incomparably harder to understand compared to an online guide like [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) *(note that this might only be the case in my country)*.

What choices do I have *(getting certified is a bonus)*?

***Addendum***: My biggest problem with a university was that it is hard to bridge the gap between what I learned in high school and the undergraduate topics. For example, it was hard to grok calculus back then so I chose to go to a teacher and after a few weeks with him, I was like "this is so simple I don't know why I had problems". Going to a math teacher would be the best option in terms of efficiency but a good teacher is more expensive than a university course and does not come with a degree.

Comment: I would recommend Kahn Academy as an online resource for learning linear algebra and statistics (which are probably the best "undergraduate level" classes for machine learning).

Comment: [These online notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs485/2006sp/LinAlg_Complete.pdf) (Paul's notes) are also a good resource for getting started in linear algebra.

Comment: " . . . from my experience it is incomparably harder to understand compared to an online guide . . ." I know this is somewhat of a tangent but to be fair, popular math channels like the one you linked to do not go nearly as in depth to mathematical content as university courses do. If they did, very few people would have the patience to follow them.

Comment: I would highly recommend choosing a reputable textbook and working through that, using clips (the ones you linked are great) and stackexchange to supplement. I am self taught and from experience, working through multiple textbooks can be very inefficient. Also, it can be hard to tell what is important, so working through a textbook will force you to learn things (and do exercises) you might otherwise skip.

Comment: My biggest problem with a university was that it is hard to bridge the gap between what I learned in high school and the undergraduate topics. For example, it was hard to grok calculus back then so I chose to go to a teacher and after a few weeks with him, I was like *"this is so simple I don't know why I had problems"*. Going to a math teacher would be the best option in terms of efficiency but a good teacher is more expensive than a university course and does not come with a degree.

Comment: This might not directly answer your question, but since you're interested in "efficient ways to learn" I recommend Barbara Oakley's book [A Mind For Numbers](https://barbaraoakley.com/books/a-mind-for-numbers), which gives insights on how the brain learns best (especially math and science) and provides good learning tricks and strategies.

Comment: To get a taste of what the book is about look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O96fE1E-rf8).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into it!